# Rufus scheduler task picked up when running rspec

Tags: rspec-rails, rufus-scheduler

I have a scheduled task which is running every 1 minute using rufus scheduler. There is no issues with its execution. But when i try running rspec, the task runs as part of it and does not let the rspec complete. How to stop it from getting picked as part of specs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like in your scheduler initializer:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  # start scheduler and schedule stuff...
end
```

EDIT

If you want to avoid running the scheduler in presence of Rspec you can do

```
if !defined?(Rspec)
  # start scheduler and schedule stuff...
end
```

It's a bit sad to mention the test framework in the code itself. It's probably better to say "let's not run the scheduler in test mode and do:

```
if !Rails.env.test?
  # start scheduler and schedule stuff...
end
```

So that the scheduler will run in production and development (or whatever env that is not test).

Comment: I would like it to execute when the app is running in dev mode. But just want to avoid it from running as part of rspec